# CSS How to make DIV Border Dynamic in Width

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I am displaying images in HTML control horizontally. The images TABLE is inside main DIV. CSS for DIV is as follows:

```
#main
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
}
```

The problem is that main DIV border is not extending and images are dropping out of it as shown in following screenshot:

[image]

Here is the HTML scippet:

```
<body>
<div id="main">

    ...

    <table>
        <tr id="image-list">
        </tr>
    </table>

    ...

</body>
```

Please suggest how to alter code so that DIV border automically increase its width as per images in it?

Comment: You shouldn't use table element for an image list. Consider making ul/li instead of table/tr. If you need a table display, then use display: table-cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue which you are encountering - <s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xp6G/)</s>

And this is what will fix the issue, am doing nothing fancy, I assigned `width: 100%;` to the `table` element, and than am using `table-layout: fixed;` which is *important* here, and than just use `max-width: 100%;` for your `img` tag... Also make sure you use `width` for your `td` elements as well...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xp6G/1/) *(Fixed issue)*

```
#main {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
}

img {
    outline: 1px solid #eee;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
    width: 33%;
}

table tr td img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @NidaSulheri They will scale proportionally, I've not assigned any  fixed `width` on the `img` tag

Comment: Horizontal scroll bar never appears and it squeezes pictures to fit them in page :(

Comment: @NidaSulheri so you want the horizontal scroll bar to appear?

Comment: yes... and it was appearing when images were dropping outside of the DIV. I want: 1. DIV border should expand itself with respect to images in it NOT to compress images to fit in visible page layout. 2. Thus it should add horizontal scrollbar when images are more than the visible portion of page.

Comment: @NidaSulheri You should have mentioned this to me before :) here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/9xp6G/2/

Comment: That seems to be working. Also, this snippet have also solved my issue:
#main
{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 display:table;
 float: left;
}
However, I mark your answer correct. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

give :

```
table{width:100%;}
```

as well as

```
#main
{
width: 100%; /*not auto*/
 /*remaining css */
}
```

that would solve your problem

**so, final css :**

```
html, body {
    width:100%; /* important */
    height:100%; /* important */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main {
    width: 100%; /* changed*/
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
table{
    width:100%; /* changed*/
    height:auto;
    border-collapse: collapse; /* added and very important*/
    table-layout: fixed;/* added and very important*/
}
img{
    width:auto; /* change as per your need */
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto; /* important to maintain aspect ratio of images */
}
```

[<strike>**your problem**</strike>](http://jsfiddle.net/H8rnL/)

[**solution demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8rnL/2/)

Comment: I guess they think you copied the solution, so may be? though not the downvoter...

Comment: @Era : mate...i owe you big time...we are new bff's!! :D

Comment: this seems not right bcz it squeezes pictures on adding more. It does not expand the control width... What I want is to expand control horizontal width and border on adding more pictures... not compressing already uploaded ones...

Comment: thanks for tagging friends.. :) are we neighbors Mr.Alien .. ?

Answer (score -1):

Put this CSS in your stylesheet to fix it:

```
#main
{
    width: 400px /*you can give fixed value or auto value*/;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
}
#main table
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: and what if images are `500 x 500 px`??

Comment: #main
    {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
    }
    #main table img{width:500px;height:500px}